# Google Trends - delete last row if isPartial is true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-trends

Asking this question mostly to people who use google trends, although it is quite a generic one.

My code in Google Trends returns a df such as the one below.

```
              1                  2                  3
              Spain   isPartial  France  isPartial  Italy  isPartial
date
2020-10-11      41       False     37     False      25      False
2020-10-18      40       False     39     False      23      False
2020-10-25      42       True      43     True       25      True
```

Naturally, I have tried many ways to delete the last row, in case it contains True.

```
1) df2 = df[~df['isPartial].str.contains('True')]   --> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

2) df2 = df[~df.eq('True').any(1)]   --> does nothing

3) df2 = df.[~[df[.iloc[:,1]].str.contains('True')] --> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'
```

What should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for select by second level of `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df1 = df[~df.xs('isPartial', axis=1, level=1).any(1)]
print (df1)
               1                2               3          
           Spain isPartial France isPartial Italy isPartial
date                                                       
2020-10-11    41     False     37     False    25     False
2020-10-18    40     False     39     False    23     False
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.xs('isPartial', axis=1, level=1))
                1      2      3
date                           
2020-10-11  False  False  False
2020-10-18  False  False  False
2020-10-25   True   True   True
```

Comment: "Beautiful is better than ugly.
[...]
Simple is better than complex."

@jezrael Thank you!